# Getting $documents is empty on laravel-mongodb when collection is empty

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, laravel-mongodb

I am using jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB. Here code below:

```
if ($label_data_temporary_count == 0 ) {
    LabelDataTemporary::insert($old_label_data_array);
} else {
    $label_data_temporary->delete(); //delete previous data
    LabelDataTemporary::insert($old_label_data_array);
}
```

`LabelDataTemporary` is my Model.
`$old_label_data_array` is data to be inserted on `LabelDataTemporary` Model.
`$label_data_temporary_count` to check `LabelDataTemporary` Model is empty or not.

`LabelDataTemporary` Model filled with some data it's goes `else` case and everything works fine. But `LabelDataTemporary` Model is empty it goes for `if` case that's when it started thrown error below:
`$documents is empty`
`(1/1) InvalidArgumentException`

```
at InsertMany->__construct('DB_NAME', 'label_data_temporary', array(), array('writeConcern' => object(WriteConcern)))
in Collection.php line 905
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is `$old_label_data_array` an empty array in the if condition branch?

Comment: It should not be empty. Let me check.

Comment: Unforutnately `$old_label_data_array` was empty for some reason. Thanks for pointing out that. @OluwafemiSule